# Passing Variables Between Two Classes in Flutter

Tags: class, variables, flutter, dart

I am making register and login pages in flutter and facing a problem as I want to use the same variables 'email' and  'password' declared inside class _MyHomePage in main.dart file

to another class SignupPage in signup.dart file.

I already imported the files but I can not use the values in both classes

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 int _counter = 0;

String _email = '';
String _password = '';

final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

FormType _formType = FormType.login;

bool validateAndSave() {
final form = formKey.currentState;
if (form.validate()) {
  form.save();
  return true;
 //      print('Form is Valid  Email: $_email, Password: $_password');
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the data when you navigate your screen in following way.

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SignUp(email: emailvariable,pass: passvariable),
                ),
```

in following way you can receive data

```
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {

  final email;
  final pass; 
  SignUp({Key key,this.email,this.pass}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}
```

now in state widget you can access email and pass variable as

```
widget.pass and widget.email
```

Comment: It gives "no material widget found" error. I did exactly what you did, any idea what could be go wrong? In my program when user presses the edit button of a post, I'm trying to get postID of what user clicked, and give it to another class.

Comment: Wrap your sign up widget with scaffold widget because it provides material or you can use material widget as well

Comment: I edited my question just before you answered it.  Sorry, you instantly responded :) Can you check it again? I'm using a StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> to list some data from CloudFirestore.  I couldn't wrap it with scaffold, but when i wrap it with material it gave the same error. I can post as a question if you want, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

### There are two approaches for that

> Pass values through class constructor

If you don't want to go back and forth you can use this

Just in the second page use like this

```
class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  Register({Key key, this.email, this.pass});

  final String email;
  final String pass;

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.email);
    print(widget.pass);
    // to use state class values you need to use the widget as the parent class object
    return Container(
    );
  }
}
```

To pass the values in constructor

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Register(email: email, pass: pass),
  ),
```

> Store the values in global scope before routing to another page

If you have to route multiple times and even require these values further, you store the values in global file before routing to another page and access there

Make one file

### global.dart

```
library my_project.global;

// set default values for the initial run
String email = '';
String pass = '';
```

### To access the values

```
import 'global.dart' as global;

main() {
 // import the global.dart file to access the variables across the application
 global.email = 'xyz@email.com';
 print(global.email);
}
```

Comment: The first solution is going to make the same problem which is defining the same variables many times so I go with the second solution but I get this error : error: The name '_emailTest' is being referenced through the prefix 'global', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that prefix. (undefined_prefixed_name at [flutter_app_service] lib/main.dart:136)

Comment: Setting Global Variables is a not a good practice. You can send them through class constructors or use a form of State Management (ScopedModel, Redux, BLoC, etc). Flutter gives you [InheritedModel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedModel-class.html) (InheritedWidget) which allows you easily share value throughout your app without much muss.

Comment: variable name should not include _ as it makes the private in dart, try removing underscore @AlexAli

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers do not solve your issue, you can use the InheritedModel widget that's provided by Flutter. It allows you to share data between deeply nested widgets. The documentation is good and there's even a video from the Flutter team explaining how to use it: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedModel-class.html

Comment: I guess those widget are independent, but still If this is the preferred way give it a shot!